# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Pengubahan Data Pemain</title>
      <style>
         label {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
         }
      </style>   
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Pengubahan Data Pemain</h1>
      <?php

         $kunci = isset($_GET["kunci"]) ? 
                  trim($_GET["kunci"]) : "";
         $pesan = isset($_GET["pesan"]) ? 
                  trim($_GET["pesan"]) : "";

         if ($kunci !== "") {
            // Lakukan koneksi database
            $koneksi = new mysqli("localhost", "root", 
                                  "syamsunisramani", "dbartt");
            if (!$koneksi)
               die("Koneksi gagal");

            // Proses SQL
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pemain WHERE id_artt = '" . 
                   $kunci . "';";

            if ($hasil = $koneksi->query($sql)) 
               if ($hasil->num_rows > 0) {
                  print("<form action=\"pemsimp.php\" method=\"post\">");
                  print("<fieldset>");

                  while ($baris = $hasil->fetch_array()) {
                     print("<p>\n");
                     print("<label>ID ARTT:</label>\n");
                     print("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id-artt\"");
                     print("       value=\"$kunci\">\n");
                     print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"kunci\"");                     
                     print("       value=\"$kunci\">\n");
                     print("</p>\n");
                     print("<p>\n");
                     print("<label>Nama Pemain:</label>\n");
                     print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"nama-pemain\"");
                     print("       value=\"$baris[1]\">\n");                     
                     print("</p>\n");
                     print("<p>\n");
                     print("<label>Klub Pemain:</label>\n");
                     print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"klub-pemain\"");
                     print("       value=\"$baris[2]\">\n");                      

                     print("</p>\n");

                   }

                   print("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Simpan\">\n");

                   print("</fieldset>\n");
                   print("</form>\n");
               }
               else {
                  print("Data tidak ditemukan<br>");     
                  $pesan = "";
               }   
            else {
               print("Gagal memproses. Kesalahan: " . 
                     $koneksi->error . "<br>");     
               $pesan = "";      
            }   
            // Tutup koneksi   
            $koneksi->close();
         }
         else
            print("Salah pemakaian");

         // Tampilkan pesan kesalahan
         if ($pesan !== FALSE) 
            print($pesan);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>

//pemsimp.php
        <?php
       $id_artt = isset($_POST["id-artt"]) ? 
                      trim($_POST["id-artt"]) : "";

       $nama_pemain = $_POST["nama-pemain"];               
       $klub_pemain = $_POST["klub-pemain"];               

       if (empty($id_artt)) {
          die("Salah pemanggilan");
       }

       // Lakukan koneksi database
       $koneksi = new mysqli("localhost", "root", 
                             "syamsunisramani", "dbartt");
       if (!$koneksi)
          die("Koneksi gagal");

       // Proses SQL
       $sql = "UPDATE pemain SET " .
              "nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain', " .
              "klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain', " .
              "WHERE id_artt = '" . $id_artt . "';";

       $pesan = "";       
       if ($hasil = $koneksi->query($sql)) 
          $pesan = "Data pemain '$nama_pemain' telah disimpan";
       else
          $pesan = "Gagal menyimpan. Kesalahan: " . $koneksi->error;     

       // Tutup koneksi   
       $koneksi->close();

       // Redirection
       header("location: ubahpem.php?kunci=$id_artt&pesan=$pesan");
    ?>
```

-When I update the database 'dbartt' by entering 'nama_pemain' or klub_pemain value with new value.
-It shows the following error. Please fix my code.

-error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server -version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_artt = '11:22:33:44:55:66'' at line 1

Comment: Too, many, commas. Also, that stop-start coding practice is *so* ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pemain WHERE id_artt = '" . $kunci . "';";
```

to this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pemain WHERE id_artt = '" . $kunci . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistake that I found (an additional ',' and a ';') and I think that may be causing the problem.

Replace your query code like this

```
       $sql = "UPDATE pemain SET " .
              "nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain', " .
              "klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain' " .
              "WHERE id_artt = '" . $id_artt . "'";
```

Another thing is that make sure that the type of `'id_artt'` column is in a format that can accept the values like `"11:22:33:44:55:66"`

Answer (score 0):

Your **where** condition should be like this.

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM pemain WHERE id_artt = '".$kunci ."' ";

Answer (score 0):

You can write that this way...

```
 $sql = "
 UPDATE pemain 
    SET nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain'
      , klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain'
  WHERE id_artt = $id_artt;
";
```

The penultimate semi-colon isn't necessary but I like to include it so I can just copy and paste the echo into a MySQL CLI for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
with heredoc query 
$sql = <<<SQL
UPDATE pemain 
    SET nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain'
      , klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain'
  WHERE id_artt = $id_artt
SQL;
```

Comment: An explanation of what you're doing here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If we decide it turns out to be turning on the ", / comma" sign. Because according to the request for renewal permission, there can be no commas before WHERE, the comma is only used if there are still data fields to be changed. Here's the correct script:

```
"UPDATE pemain SET " .
"nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain', " .
"klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain'" .
"WHERE id_artt = '" . $id_artt . "';";
```

or

```
"UPDATE pemain SET nama_pemain = '$nama_pemain', klub_pemain = '$klub_pemain' WHERE id_artt = '$id_artt'";
```